# How do I add units to paper-slider?

Tags: html, polymer

How do I add units text to the `<paper-slider>` value (after or before the slider)? For example, I'd like something like "km" range.

```
<paper-slider value="{{menzil}}" min="0" max="50" step="10" name="Km" label="KM" pin snaps editable suffix="Km"></paper-slider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [`<paper-slider>`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/blob/8a9845210aed5c14ef7ec687ec3d26bf09f15aa9/paper-slider.html#L337) I'm tempted to say you got to implement your own 'paper-slider' and do something like:

```
<div id="sliderKnob"
    class="slider-knob"
    on-down="_knobdown"
    on-up="_resetKnob"
    on-track="_onTrack"
    on-transitionend="_knobTransitionEnd">
      <div class="slider-knob-inner" value$="[[immediateValue]] <-- Custom Extension Here -->"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe not the most satisfying solution though.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. :)

Comment: While editing the <paper-slider> best solution was for me that I add one line before paper-input:   <div suffix>Km</div>
      </paper-input>   (But need to change also at style .slider-input width up to desired size. )